# How to compile c++ programs in the new c++ driver provided by Datastax in Linux

Tags: cql

I am new to Cassandra. I installed c++ driver from Datastax. Can some one please provide me the steps like in which path I have to create the ‘.c’ file and how I can compile it. I can see some example programs in example folder. Can anyone plz tell me how to compile the example programs.

Answer (score 1):

The cpp-driver uses cmake and depends on libuv.  So the first steps would be to ensure you have cmake installed as well as libuv. Depending on your linux distribution it may be as simple as using package manager like apt or yum (i.e. `sudo apt-get install cmake libuv-dev`)

Building is just a matter of running the following steps in the cpp-driver directory:

1. `cmake .`
2. `make`
3. `sudo make install`

This will install libcassandra.so to somewhere in your lib path.   You can then link by providing '-lcassandra' in your parameters to clang or gcc (i.e. `clang myfile.c -o myfile -lcassandra`)

There is very comprehensive documentation on building from source [here](http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/).

Comment: Thanks Andy.. I was looking for '-lcassandra' part.  Any link explaining these basic steps and small examples to understand Cassandra with C++ will help me a lot. Can you suggest me any such web link. Thanks in advance. I finished all the installation steps for the cpp-driver.

Comment: @NarayanaVasa this guide should help you get started: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/getting-started-with-the-datastax-c-driver